# Property "gluonfx.target" not defined in example Gluon JavaFX app starers

Tags: maven, javafx, graalvm, gluon, gluon-desktop

I am trying to use the *Gluon Desktop* tools to make a JavaFX app. I have tried creating a new Maven-driven app in both of these ways:

- The [Gluon Start](https://start.gluon.io/) web app
- The *Gluon - Single View Project* new project template provided by the [Gluon plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7864-gluon) for IntelliJ.

In both cases, the provided POM file uses a property named `gluonfx.target` in this line:

```xml
<target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
```

Further down in the POM, a couple of `profile` elements defines `gluonfx.target` for values of `ios` and `android`. But:

1. those definitions do not prevent IntelliJ from reporting the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'gluonfx.target'`; and
2. I am trying to build a [Gluon Desktop](https://gluonhq.com/products/desktop/) app, not an iOS or Android app.

Is the `gluonfx.target` property defined somewhere outside the POM? Or am I supposed to define that property? If so, where and how? Should I add an element to the `properties` element of the POM? If so what are the possible values for the property? Or is a `profile` element missing for development of a desktop app?

Here is an entire provided POM (modified by me to use Java 20):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluon-singleviewproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Gluon-SingleViewProject</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>20</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>20</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.18</attach.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.19</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>work.basil.example.GluonApplication</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` property for the GluonFX maven/gradle plugins is defined here: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_target

> A string that defines the target platform. The default is `host`, which refers to the platform that currently hosts the process. It can be set also to `ios` to create native images for iOS devices (Aarch64), or `android` to create native images for Android devices (Aarch64).
>
> Default: `host`

If you don't set the target value, it defaults to `host`, which is the target for a desktop application, to run on Linux, macOS or Windows.

For other platforms (mobile or embedded), you need to set a different value.

While the Gluon samples, do [define](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/pom.xml#L23) the maven property:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <gluonfx.target>host</gluonfx.target>
</properties>
```

this doesn't apply to the samples generated from the GluonFX IDE plugins or [start.gluon.io](https://start.gluon.io), though this doesn't really matter, given that the default `host` will be used.

In any case, since IntelliJ does complain about the missing value, this can be easily fix, adding such property to the pom (and removing the mobile profiles if not needed):

```
<properties>
    ...
    <gluonfx.target>host</gluonfx.target>
</properties>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
     ...
    </plugin>
...
</plugins>

<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
...
</profiles>
```

Note that if you define an empty or a non valid target, you will get a runtime exception when you try `mvn gluonfx:build`.